# JavaScript and regular expressions: literal syntax Vs. RegExp object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some troubles with this small JavaScript code:

```js
var text="Z Test Yeah ! Z";

// With literal syntax, it returns true: good!
alert(/(Z[\s\S]*?Z)/g.test(text));

// But not with the RegExp object O_o
var reg=new RegExp('Z[\s\S]*?Z','g');
alert(reg.test(text));
```

I don't understand why the literal syntax and the RegExp object don't give me the same result...
The problem is that I have to use the RegExp object since I'll have some variables later.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to double escape `\` characters in string literals, which is why the regex literal is typically preferred.

Try:

```
'Z[\\s\\S]*?Z'
```

Comment: It's correct, with backslashes it works...! Thank you so much, since we don't need them with literal syntax, I didn't think that they are mandatory for RegExp object. Thank you again!

Comment: @zzzzBov Why do we need to escape the `\\` in the second case and not the first case?

Comment: @Geek, the first regular expression used is a RegExp literal. The second regular expression used is a RegExp object constructor with a string literal as an argument. My answer specifically says you need to double escape ``\`` characters in string literals. For string literals, ``\`` is used to create escape sequences for values, whereas in a regular expression we want the escape sequence to *be* the value. ``"\n"`` creates a string with a value of newline, whereas ``"\\n"`` creates a string with a value of ``\n``. The distinction is very important for regular expression patterns.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you have to escape your backslashes, even when using single quotes. Try this:

```
new RegExp('Z[\\s\\S]*?Z','g')
```